# set dynamic email to received order email when the order is placed in magento 2 programically

Tags: magento-2.1

i need your help to set a dynamic email along with store id email which received the order  details when the new order places .Meanwhile which file i need to setup my custom email .

i have check the "Send Order Email Copy To" option in admin panel i need that file which that code is explored so i can put my email code over there can anyone help me.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create observer on Order success:

Defile event in `etc/event.xml`

```
<event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action">
    <observer name="<vendor>_order_success_save_after" instance="<VendorName>\<ModuleName>\Observer\Order\CopyEmail"  />
</event>
```

Create Observer to send copy order details Email:

Path : `YourModule/Observer/Order/CopyEmail`

`CopyEmail.php`:

```
<?php
 /**
  * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
  * See COPYING.txt for license details.
  */
 namespace <VendorName>\<moduleName>\Observer\Order;

 use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
 use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
 use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;


 class CopyEmail implements ObserverInterface
 {

     /**
      * @var \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface
      */
     protected $_objectManager;


     protected $_transportBuilder;

     /** 
      * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Collection
      */
    protected $orders;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $_scopeConfig;

    /**
     * @param UrlPersistInterface $urlPersist
     */

   public function __construct(
      \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager,
      \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,
      \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
       \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
        )
     {
         $this->_objectManager          = $objectmanager;
         $this->_scopeConfig            = $scopeConfig;
         $this->_transportBuilder       = $transportBuilder;
         $this->_orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
     }

/**
 * Generate urls for UrlRewrite and save it in storage
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
 * @return void
 */
public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
{

    $customerSession = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');


   $this->order = $observer->getEvennt()->getOrder();
        $emailTemplateVariables = array();
        $customerFirstName = $this->order->getCustomerFirstname();
        $customerLastName = $this->order->getCustomerLastname();
        $url = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')
            ->getStore()
            ->getBaseUrl();

        $emailTempVariables['orderid'] = $this->order->getEntityId();
        $emailTempVariables['firstname'] = $customerFirstName;
        $emailTempVariables['lastname'] = $customerLastName;


        $senderName = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('trans_email/ident_general/name',ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);

        $senderEmail = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('trans_email/ident_general/email',ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);

        $postObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
        $postObject->setData($emailTempVariables);

        $sender = [
            'name' => $senderName,
            'email' => $senderEmail,
        ];
        $email = $this->order->getCustomerEmail();

        $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;

        /*Email Template Id*/
        $templateId = '<YourEmailTemplate>';

        $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($templateId)
            ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, 'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID])
            ->setTemplateVars(['data' => $postObject])
            ->setFrom($sender)
            ->addTo($email)
            ->setReplyTo($senderEmail)
            ->getTransport();

        $transport->sendMessage();
   }
}
```

Create you Email Template and set order details as per your need.

Comment: Thanks for response but i am still not getting any email with code i have create a custom module for it. could you please  help me on it.

Comment: Are you checking it in your local server ?

Comment: No i am check it on live server

Comment: Try to exit on observer, as if it's called or not .