# How to send email admin dynamically when order placed

Tags: admin, event-observer, system.xml, system-configuration, magento2.3.5-p1

In this I want to create custom module for Send email to admin from one email sending field to get email id and send email on that id after order placed successfully using event and observer and one system config field for entering email address.

please anyone can have idea about this functionality then please answer this question as soon as possible.

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: can you check this link --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/172156/set-dynamic-email-to-received-order-email-when-the-order-is-placed-in-magento-2 2) https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/229722/how-to-send-different-order-emails-to-admin-and-customer-in-magento-2

Comment: Thanks for sending this solution

Comment: Welcome @Deep Shah

Comment: I Want to create email custom field in admin panel for entering email id